# IIS Express MVC Remote Debugging SSL connection Error

Tags: android, asp.net-mvc, ssl, iis

I am trying to remotely debug an MVC application on a android Chrome browser. I have enabled my IIS express to my local network and also configured my `applicationhost.config` file to have the following bindings

```
<bindings>
 <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:62442:localhost" />
 <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:62442:xxx.xxx.x.xxx" />     
</bindings>
```

I have also created a new `InBound` rule in Windows Firewall with the port number.

When I try to open the mvc web app in my android device (Chrome) it gives me the following error

`SSL Connection Error`

`Unable to make a secure connection to the server. This may be a problem with the server or it may be requiring a client authentication certificate that you don't have`

I am not sure how to get rid of the SSL error?

Answer (score 2):

You can use our free VS Extension called 'Conveyor' to enable remote connections to IIS Express.

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vs-publisher-1448185.ConveyorbyKeyoti

That way you don't need to work with bindings config (Conveyor doesn't touch them either).